# Генерировать число на основе последнего записанного в базу

Tags: pdo, sql, php, mysql

Приветствую. Как можно сгенерировать значение для поля id пользователя (поле типа varchar) по шаблону 000001, 000002 и т.д.? То есть при регистрации нового пользователя для него нужно сгенерировать userid на основе последней userid в таблице. Скажем если последний userid это 000012, то следующий зарегистрированный пользователь должен получить номер 000013. К сожалению не силен в SQL и PHP, но нужно именно с применением этих технологий и желательно бы с PDO, но это не критично.

Comment: А почему нельзя использовать автоикремент? Зачем какие-то велосипеды с варчаром и нулями?

Comment: @ua6xh

    К сожалению не силен в SQL 

Иначе бы, чисто теоретически, судя по ведущим нулям, вполне хватило бы char =)

Comment: > К сожалению не силен в SQL и PHP, но нужно именно с применением этих технологий

кому нужно ?

Comment: Если Вы не догадливый, это нужно тому, кто задал вопрос, иначе бы он его не задавал, правильно?

Comment: @Lucky, это вы недогадливый, если вы не сильны в PHP и SQL, как вы можете знать, что вам нужны эти технологии для решения этой задачи ? Поэтому я и спросил "кому нужно?" потому-что учитывая выше сказанное, спрашивающему это не может быть нужно.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Следующий номер можно найти, например, так:

```
select right(concat('00000000000000000',max(id)+1),length(max(id))) from t;
```

Comment: Не учите ерунде ) есть автоикремент ). А то чтобы присесть нужно сбегать на завод и попросить произвести стул!

Во вторых в данном случае нужна блокировка таблицы.

Comment: Я дал точный ответ на поставленный вопрос. А учить - это вы пытаетесь.

Comment: Цель данного сайта все-таки немного больше, чем просто отвечать на заданные вопросы.

Comment: Если мой ответ не отвечает целям хозяев сайта, я готов понести самое суровое наказание.

Comment: @msi не надо все максимилизировать )

Comment: @Fike, договорились. Я минимизирую свой участие в этом обсуждении до 0.

Comment: В общем сделал примерно так же, но с небольшими поправками. Добавил условие, что если последний userid > 9, то спереди добавлять на 1 ведущий ноль меньше.

Comment: А если больше 99?

Comment: @LinnTroll, и на 99 тоже условие есть :)

Comment: @Lucky, а Вы уверены, что все запросы, использующие этот механизм будут **всегда** выполняться **последовательно**?

Если нет, то Вам предстоит еще и разработка механизма блокировок совместного использования таблицы. 

Это может привести к ужасному падению производительности.

Answer (score 5):

В таблице пользователей создайте поле userid (int) с auto_increment
Подробнее читайте [тут](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/example-AUTO_INCREMENT.html)

Поле с auto_increment при добавлении новой записи в таблицу автоматически подставляет число +1 от максимального в этом поле.

Comment: @terantul, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Comment: auto_increment не подойдет. Насколько я понял, он добавляет +1 на основе какого-то кэша, так как при авттоинкременте id, даже если удалить все данные из таблицы, он уже начинает не с 1, а с того цифры, которая была последней, даже если записей уже нет в таблице.

Comment: @Lucky

* Я не думаю, что планета рухнет из-за такого айдишника
* auto increment беспроблемно сбрасывается на **любое** значение
* при первой же concurrency race полезут ошибки из-за занятого ключа.

Проще все-таки передать эту работу БД.

Comment: @Fike говорит верно. auto increment без проблемно сбрасывается на любое значение.

          TRUNCATE your_table - очистить таблицу и сбросить на 0ъ
          ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT= X
Где X -  то чило, с которого хотите начать.

Comment: @Victor Halauko, ну скажем так, таблица в бд будет периодически очищаться и каждый первый новый пользователь должен получать все тот же 000001.

Comment: >автоинкремент хранит в int, а у него нет ведущих нулей, а мне еще нужно делать экспорт в pdf, чтобы показывать этот список людям

Вам никогда не приходило в голову,  что данные из бд совсем не обязательно отображать в pdf один в один? Что их перед этим можно  и нужно форматировать и преобразовывать в требуемый вид? База данных это сущность другого порядка, она не должна подгоняться под нужды отображения. 
Дело ваше, конечно, но я бы за такое "решение" отправил сотрудника на неделю в техподдержку разгребать письма от индусов